# How to test Windows Firewall rules?

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

[image: My windows event viewer shows 58.222.20.18 tries to log into my machine.]

My windows event viewer shows 58.222.20.18 tries to log into my machine. I believe my Windows Firewall should have blocked 58.222.20.18. However, my firewall has hundreds of rules, it's infeasible to go through each rule and evaluate them with my brain.

Is it possible for Windows Firewall to tell me for a given request, whether it will be blocked or not?

Comment: perhaps its time to consider why your firewall rule-set is so unwieldy.

Comment: @FrankThomas Exactly! I have added a blocked-all rule. But how can I verify it's working? (in case I turned off the firewall)

Comment: The connection wasn't blocked, so you already know you don't have a firewall rule that will block the connection. Given that, what is your question?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator My question is, I just added a blocked-all rule, but how can I verify it's working? Do you want me to contact the owner of 58.222.20.18 and ask him/her to test again?

Comment: @Gqqnbig since a "deny all" rule will block *any* connection, then you can test by attempting any connection. Our do you perhaps mean that you created a block all rule *only for that specific source address*? If so, then yes, the only way to test that is to initiate traffic from that source.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I heard of IP spoofing. Is it possible to send a package from my IP, but claims the source IP to be another? What tool can do that?